# Sending HTTP GET request using WebServiceTemplate and SOAP

Tags: java, spring, soap

I'm trying to send a GET request to a server using SOAP using WebServiceTemplate, but I'm unable to do so. How do I set query params and send the request? I tried constructing a String URL and using marshalSendAndReceive(url, null), but it threw an exception.

I'm using Java and Spring Boot to get this done.

```java
result = (TransactionResult) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(uri + "?" + uri2, (Object) null);
```

Error Message:

```
Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to create envelope from given source:
```

Stack Trace

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Unable to create envelope from given source: ; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Unable to create envelope from given source: 
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:216) ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60) ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92) ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:611) ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-2.4.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive
```

Comment: Log your requests. Looks like the root element of the xml document you are sending is not named "Envelope" as expected. What's the reason for making a GET call to a SOAP service?

Comment: It is mentioned in the spec that all requests should be made using GET call. I tried putting the name of XmlRootElement as Envelope, I got the same error.

Comment: You cannot web services are POST by contract. So I suspect you are simply using the wrong tool `WebServiceTemplate` for the job. You are probably not accessing a SOAP web service but just a regular XML based service...

Comment: Why not use RestTemplate instead and post "Envelope" with content type "text/xml". Try it in Postman(or any other tool you have available) first before writing any code, then work from your Postman call to write code.